# How would you configure Nginx as a forward/reverse Proxy for an AWS API Gateway that implements mtls?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, aws-api-gateway

Been struggling with an Nginx(1.18.0) configuration for a forward proxy. We use specific EC2 boxes as forward proxies and that allows us to send their EIP for whitelisting purpose. So Nginx has been used for several cases including mtls and that had always worked fine. But this time the partner is using AWS API Gateway and this seems not to work. When I used curl and openssl with the client cert and key it works fine but as long as I am using nginx it still throws an http error 400.

Below is the configuration I am currently using.

```
server {

    listen         11013;
    server_name    localhost;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/forward_partner_x_nginx_proxy_access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/forward_partner_x_nginx_proxy_error.log warn;

    proxy_ssl_certificate /root/partner_x_ssl/uat_chain.crt;
    proxy_ssl_certificate_key /root/partner_x_ssl/uat.key;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    set  $partner_x_upstream https://api.partner_x.app;


    location /test {
                        access_log off;
                        return 200;
                }


    location / {
                        proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host;
                        proxy_pass $partner_x_upstream;
                        #proxy_pass_request_headers      on;

                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
                        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                        proxy_buffering off;
                        proxy_ssl_name xx.xx.xx.xx;
                        #add_header Content-Type application/json;
                }

}
```

I have tried several iteration of this config and it still didn't work. Because of the client certificate, i am not able to see anything significant over a captured tcpdump.

has anyone able to have a similar config working ? Grateful if you could share some lights on what I am doing wrong here. Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

Comment: Have you remembered to `symlink`? It's another common problem that makes `nginx` to throw `400`.

Comment: Yes, I have done all that. It doesn't work well with Amazon API Gateway with client SSL I guess. I switched to envoy proxy and it works well. So I moved on